# show/hide a part of shortcode if an attribute value is 0

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

hi guys i want to hide a part of shortcode when an attribute value like closebutton is 0.
this is the code that i use

```
function atalertshortcode($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "class" => '',"text" => '',"size" => '',"closebutton" => '',"other" => ''
), $atts));
return '<div class="uk-alert '.$class.' '.$size.'" data-uk-alert="" '.$other.'><a href="" class="uk-alert-close uk-close"></a> '.$text.' </div>';}
```

i want to hide this part of shortcode when closebutton value is 0

```
<a href="" class="uk-alert-close uk-close"></a>
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function atalertshortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "class" => '',
        "text" => '',
        "size" => '',
        "closebutton" => '',
        "other" => '',
    ), $atts));

    $output = '<div class="uk-alert ' . $class . ' ' . $size . '" data-uk-alert="" ' . $other . '>';
    if ($closebutton) {
        $output .= '<a href="" class="uk-alert-close uk-close"></a>';
    }
    $output .= ' ' . $text . '</div>';

    return $output;
}
```

This basically requires you to separate the output in several pieces, and wrap the optional portion in an IF block to check the required condition (in this case we're checking if $closebutton does not evaluate to 0 in any way, and if it doesn't, the link is added to the shortcode output).

Comment: thanks for your help now if it has a custom value like show for showing content and hide for hiding content , what i can do ?

Comment: Simply replace 

`if ($closebutton) {` 

with 

`if ($closebutton == 'show') {`

or with

`if ($closebutton == 'hide') {` 

depending on the condition you want to use.